# Simplifying partial derivative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have trouble understanding how this simplification was done. Can anyone explain please?

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial M}=\frac{5}{6}\frac{2^{1/3}3^{1/2}}{5^{5/6}}\frac{M^{-1/6}}{p_1^{1/3}p_2^{1/2}}=\frac{5^{1/6}}{2^{2/3}3^{1/2}p_1^{1/3}p_2^{1/2}}M^{-1/6}$

Thanks for your help.
Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides some rearrangements, all the simplification comes in the numeric terms through factorisation and applying exponent rules:

$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{5}{6} \frac{2^{1/3} 3^{1/2}}{5^{5/6}} & = & \frac{5}{2 \times 3} \frac{2^{1/3} 3^{1/2}}{5^{5/6}} \\
& = & \frac{5^{6/6}}{5^{1/6}}  \frac{2^{1/3}}{2^{3/3}} \frac{3^{1/2}}{3^{2/2}} \\
& = & 5^{5/6} \frac{1}{2^{2/3}} \frac{1}{3^{1/2}}\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: I see! thank you, much appreciated

Comment: I think you have a typo at the second line: $=\frac{5^{6/6}}{5^{1/6}}  \frac{2^{1/3}}{2^{3/3}} \frac{3^{1/2}}{3^{\color{red}2/2}}$

Comment: I do, thanks for catching it